# How can I navigate webbrowser synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webbrowser-control, synchronous

I have looked around quite a time and I have noticed that everybody saying that webbrowser is working asynchronously, and I think its wrong, because when I trigger Navigate and even implement the documentComplete event, nothing happens.

I have noticed that when the main thread (the thread that owns the webbrowser) has done his job only then the webbrowser start navigating, probably because after that the browser will use the main thread to execute his commands.

now that not good because I want to be able to control the timing, I want to be able to know when the webbrowser done loading the page and then to continue with my work. Polling doesn't work here because of what I said earlier, the webbrowser doesn't even start navigating.

example:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

browser.Navigate(url);
while(browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
}

// Then executing the next steps...
```

How can I use the WebBrowser synchronously so I can be able to use the document property and other stuff of the WebBrowser, I want to create some sort of a blocking method So I can have control and know when the WebBrowser done loading.

Comment: Ah, active waiting without sleep. Not the best way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you navigate your main thread will not wait for document complete. So you need to block it via a global varibale. A dirty solution can be;

```
        bool IsReady;
    void Go()
    {
        IsReady = false;
        brw.Navigate("url");
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (!IsReady);
    }

   void brw_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsReady = true;
    }
```

But the trick here is when an exception happens it will silently stop your code without any explicit exception. So I strongly advice using webbrowser related code inside a try catch block.

Comment: Man you are the first person that gave the right solution thank a lot! But I must know why it didn't handle the document_Complete event before? maybe because the browser was handling others events at the time and cause blocking?

Comment: If you dont call ApplicationDoEvents() inside do-while loop webbrowser can't calll documentcompleted event as it is single threaded.

Comment: So the webbrowser do use the main thread? and that's why it didn't navigate at all?

Comment: Your while loop may not prevent navigating. (I think webbrowser navigates acync) But this loop will prevent form invalidation and other updates. So you may not see the new page as nothing drawn. Again Application.DoEvents() enables us see what has happened.

Comment: One last thing, I think that the loop isn't related to what you said because if I will do Thread.Sleep(some time) the webbrowser won't not navigate at this time means that the webbrowser isn't asnyc am I right? Thank a lot for all the help you are great =]